# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: MenuBottomSheetFragment{d476429 #0}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1891)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:760)
```

My code when open clicked `MenuBottomSheetFragment`:

```
private void openBottomSheet() {
        if (mMenuBottomSheetFragment == null)
            mMenuBottomSheetFragment = new MenuBottomSheetFragment();
        if (!mMenuBottomSheetFragment.isShowing())
            mMenuBottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mMenuBottomSheetFragment.getTag());
    }
```

And my `MenuBottomSheetFragment` have nothing special.

I really have no idea why. Most of the time, `MenuBottomSheetFragment` works fine. But some time, it throws this *Exception* then I do nothing.

So what is the problem in my case? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the isShowing with this:

```
 if(!mMenuBottomSheetFragment.isAdded()) {
      mMenuBottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mMenuBottomSheetFragment.getTag());
 }
```

Comment: Use live data will be even better, you won't need to check for conditions and in the above case what you are trying to show might be missed, for example if your code gets executed before the inflation, but with live data its guaranteed that the code inside the condition will be executed because it happens inside the activity/fragment lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

The fragment has already been added. There is no need to show it again. Just check it after the `null`-check and return if it's added:

```
if(mMenuBottomSheetFragment.isAdded()) {
    return;
}
```